# Know when ko.applyBindings(vm) ends and call vm.anymethod()

Tags: knockout.js

Is there anyway we can know when ko.applyBindings(VM) finishes and then call any method defined inside VM only once when the page loads or users refreshes (F5).
I want something like the one discussed on this google group:-

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/E_r-9-79B_U

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? The bindings are applied synchronously so it is finished when it returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ko.applyBindings()` is synchronous, so it's done at the next statement:

```
 var vm = new MyViewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(vm);
 // now bindings are done!!
 vm.DoSomethingCool();
```

In the past, I've included an observable property in my view model called `initialized` which is set to `false` in the constructor but is set to `true` immediately after `applyBindings`. I've used binding attached to that property to hide everything while the binding is being done and then make it visible once it's done.